# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence : max() function gives this error

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, max

i have a data frame name mapped value, which contains list

mapped value

[1,2,3,4]

[1,2,3,4,5]

[1,2]

Expected output:

4

5

2
, I am trying to print the maximum value and trying to put it into new column

```
df['new column'] = df['mapped value'].max()
```

but it gives me an error
**ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence**, any idea where am i going wrong?

[enter link description here][1]

Here is my data:
[1]: https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/filse.csv

Answer (score 2):

Problem is there is some empty list, possible solution is use lambda functon with `if-else`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mapped value':[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2],[]]})

df['new column'] = df['mapped value'].apply(lambda x: max(x) if bool(x) else np.nan)
print (df)
      mapped value  new column
0     [1, 2, 3, 4]         4.0
1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]         5.0
2           [1, 2]         2.0
3               []         NaN
```

Comment: i still get the same error, ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: @MayuriPandey - Can you check now?

Comment: Hi it worked, i understood the issue, but what i directly needed integer values like 4, 5, 2 etc not float 4.0,5.0? if you could tell, it would be helpful.Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MayuriPandey - then use `pd.NA` instead `np.nan` - [integer NaN](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) or `df['mapped value'].apply(lambda x: max(x) if bool(x) else np.nan).astype('Int64')`